# Why is the Z size inversed in surf function

Tags: matlab, graphics, graph, plot, matlab-figure

Looking at the definition of surf, I found this :

*surf(X,Y,Z) uses Z for the color data and surface height. X and Y are vectors or matrices defining the x and y components of a surface. If X and Y are vectors, length(X) = n and length(Y) = m, where [m,n] = size(Z).*

It looks quite counter-intuitive to me that X would be first and Y second, but that Z would be Y first and X second in terms of size.

Having data that represents real information, it is really harassing to deal with this all the time, having to reshape so that my data will be as it should be when I plot it.

Anyone has a decent explanation for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation probably has to do with the fact that you are dealing with matrices. The first index of a matrix refers to the **row**, which is naturally associated with the ***y* axis** (up-down). The second is the **column**, corresponding to ***x* axis (left-right)**.

Anyway, the only thing you have to do to interchange *x* and *y* in `Z` is to transpose: use `Z.'` as input to `surf`.

(Decent enough?) :-)

Comment: Yeah, I do transpose in my code. It just felt odd to me. But this looks like the most likely explanation (though the FORTRAN one is kind of funny too).

Comment: @Vissenbot I suggest another workaround: since X and Y are most probably uni-dimensionnal, you could write `surf(x.',y.',z.');` though you would not be in a position to understand what motivates such a silly rule, you would at least contemplate an appearance of homogeneity. Seriously, don't do it, it's a joke, just to prove how absurd the implementation is.

Answer (score 0):

My theory is that Matlab was first written in FORTRAN which has a column-major order.

Then it was re-written in C which is row-major, but for backward compatibility column-major order was kept for Matlab matrices.

I'm quite sure that 3D graphics were written directly in C. Naively connecting row major 3D primitives with column-major Matlab matrices potentially creates such inversion in surf.

This is only a theory, but I'd like to be proven wrong!

If my theory is right, then the convolutions spent at explaining why meshgrid should be like it is in Matlab documentation make me ROTFL :)

Comment: A hint to flesh out the theory would be to check this kind of inversion ncolum,nrow instead of nrow,ncolumn in java/C source code, something like surf_primitive( zdata , ncolumn , nrow )

Comment: Interesting theory, however, my assumtion is that this is rather connected to the mathematical indexing A_i,j where i are rows and j are columns. After all it is just syntax right?

Comment: @patrik just type `[x,y,z]=meshgrid(1:2,10:10:30,100:100:400);` it's working like German, huntert, drei und zwanzig... Then type `help meshgrid` and read carefully to convince you that there is something weird in surf... It's just conventions after all, but completely surprising ones.

Comment: I still does not get why it is weird. If you use matrices you need to use the same convention as in algebra, so to say row-column, everything else is confusing. If you use x,y,z, you want the variables in that order. This is how you normally define the variables in maths. This is an as good reason as any to use the same convention in matlab. However, and here comes what I think is the twist. In graphics programming, the coordinate system is usually defined with y pointing downward. So if you think it is weird it is probably a window/linux/(3rd party API to C) thing.

Comment: @patrik No, forget a moment about graphics. Meshgrid is weird per se. I ask to generate a cartesian product of 3 arrays a,b,c `[a,b,c]=meshgrid(1:2,10:10:30,100:100:400);` (a lot like ind2sub sub2ind). And what meshgrid does is making b index vary first, then a index, then c index, which you can check by typing `b(:),a(:),c(:)`. Compare results with ndgrid, and tell me if, oh it's natural. This inversion has been performed in order to comply with surf. IMO definitely weird.

Comment: Well I guess that it is a matter of opinion. It is correct assuming the coordinate system have the y-axis 90 degrees to the right of the x-axis. However, the x-axis is then no longer pointing left to right, but up to down. This is extremely confusing. Not to mention all the problems that would appear with the use of `image`. See you are saying that I need to forget about graphics when discussing a function creating graphics. And the variables `a,b,c` is **not** indices, but coordinates. They should not be mixed up with indices.

Comment: When dealing with coordinates index is a forbidden word. It is like saying that liear algebra is wrong because the first index goes from up to down since x, which uses to be the first variable normally goes from left to right. What I mean is that it simply makes no sense.

Comment: @patrik i asked to forget about graphics and concentrate on meshgrid per se, but apparently, reaching this level of abstraction is too hard. Explain why the hell there is meshgird+ndgrid. From first principles, there are two different ways to do the same thing and that's one more than necessary - whatever the usage (graphics) or implementation (indices)... Without knowing the internals, ndgrid is completely consistent with ind2sub and sub2ind, meshgrid is not: it has a weird inversion. Looking at implementation details, ndgrid appears as consistent with universally used column-major order

Comment: Why would you ever want to store a meshgrid as an one dimensional array? This would be like creating a picture of every brick in super mario bros. Why I cannot see the problem is because the sole purpose of `meshgrid` is to create a grid to mesh and surf. Since this is the purpose you want to use the same convention as the coordinate system in the figure. Anything else would be confusing. That coordinate system is **not** cartesian since `y` is inverted. However, this means that x has the expected direction on a 2D image. This is probably completely intentional and goes long way back.

Comment: Think about it how would you define your coordinates to make them consistent with a pixel grid (3D-RGB matrix) and still not mess up the directions. If you think about it you would see that this is the best solution. Creating a `surf` plot is doing graphics and you would want the convention here to be as similar as possible to other graphics applications. You cannot say that something should be done in some way because that makes more sense to you. It definitely makes little or no sense to how the function interacts with other software.

Comment: @patrik you did not answer: why two ways meshgrid + ndgrid to do the same work? if you think about the unecessary complexity it introduces, how you're going to explain in user manual in which case you should use one or the other, and how users will be confused about un-natural ordering of parameters when picking the wrong one, you'll see that surf API has been a wrong programmer decision to the detriment of user and principle of least astonishment. I've been surprised, vissenbot too, many others too. Existence of meshgrid+ndgrid is a clue that the implementation sucks due to indexing problem.

Comment: Well imo it is `ndgrid` that is the one that is the problematic one. However the functions may have different purposes. I still think it is good to have one function that works well with graphics (eg `image`) and one that can be used if you want a cartesian grid. For me `meshgrid` worked perfectly as I expected the first time. However once I had some serious issues with transposing a cartesian grid on several places since I wanted to print some results as an image. The reason you have indexing problems is since you expect x (1st mtx idx) to be vertical and that would certainly be surprising!

Comment: @patrik meshgrid is a cartesian grid as well as ndgrid. It's just that it's been twisted to fit surf implementation, and i see the whole as a design mistake. Every matlab user is sooner or later exposed to this unecessary complexity and to unecessary astonishment moments. The fact that the mistake is due to C vs FORTRAN indexing is pure speculation, but the fact that it is a mistake is... well just a fact.

Comment: @patrik ndgrid is more natural than meshgrid for the same reason that 1,2,3 is a more natural ordering than 2,1,3. If you really want to stick on graphics, you can't speculate how I see X,Y,Z, I worked in aerospace and satellites and I am prepared for rotations > 90°, so my sole expectation is to have right handed trihedron and consistent and natural X,Y,Z ordering all the way down. The order Z,X,Y would be OK, but Y,X,Z to me is like having a left handed trihedron, so it is not an allowed permutation. Though it's that of surf API (Y,X,Z(iX,jY) )